# C# bool operations to detect any false return

Tags: c#, boolean

I'd like to write something like the following....

```
bool hasAnyInvalid = false;
hasAnyInvalid |= IsValidType1(...);
hasAnyInvalid |= IsValidType2(...);
hasAnyInvalid |= IsValidType3(...);
hasAnyInvalid |= IsValidType4(...);

if (hasAnyInvalid){ return false; }
```

As far as I can tell, the above will fail because true | true is false.

How can I use one boolean variable to test multiple functions for a false?

I need to evaluate each of the IsValidType functions. So I can't short-circuit it out.

Basically, I want a logic gate that once it goes true, it stays true. I seem to recall doing this in the past in C++ with HRESULT returns, but we may have simply been adding up the integer value of the severity.

I'm open to other ways of solving this.

EDIT:
I poorly phrased this question, and included a few logical snafus ( I meant to write this as an XOR ). 
I'm going to leave my original question above because people specifically commented about it, and I hate to alter history.

Comment: Isn't `|` the bitwise `OR` operator? So `true | true` is `true`. And `true | false` will also be `true`, so it will stay true once it goes true. I don't see the problem OP. Did you actually _test_ it before making the assumption it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to detect a single `false`, you need to use an `&`, not an `|`:

```
bool allValid = true; // Start it with "true"
allValid &= IsValidType1(...); // The first "false" will make "allValid" false
allValid &= IsValidType2(...);
allValid &= IsValidType3(...);
allValid &= IsValidType4(...);
if (!allValid) { // Invert "allValid" before returning
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving a good name to the variable and its initial value

Comment: I don't think he wants to know if ALL are valid. He wants to know if ANY are valid.

Comment: @JimRhodes He wants to know if any are *invalid* (which is another way of saying `!allValid`) :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight He states: "once it goes true, it stays true". That sounds like any to me.

Comment: @JimRhodes Judging from the variable's name, OP's talking about the inverse (see "user2576520" for an alternative implementation of the same piece of logic).

Comment: This answer was what I was looking for. I did poorly express my question initially, and used two opposite variable names to obfuscate the question even further. Also, for some reason I convinced myself that False &= False was true.

Answer (score 4):

This will *not* short-circuit the evaluation of the *functions* for their values, and will return `true` if *any* of the functions return false.

```
bool[] results = new[] {
    IsValidType1(),
    IsValidType2(),
    IsValidType3(),
    IsValidType4() 
};
return results.Any(b => !b);
```

Note that it *reads* like your requirement: return `true` if *any* of the results are `false`.

> I need to evaluate each of the IsValidType functions. So I can't short-circuit it out.

This must mean that the functions have side effects that you need to observe. Just make sure that you document your code so that no one sees this and doesn't realize that changing it to short-circuit the function evaluation could introduce bugs by removing the side effects.

> As far as I can tell, the above will fail because `true | true` is `false`.

I am not sure what makes you think that. `true | true`, that is `true or true` is `true`. You *might* be thinking of `xor`, but that would be `true ^ true`.

Comment: I was in XOR land. Sorry, no coffee yet.

Comment: Also, +1 because I did not think to do that with an array. This doesn't make sense in my current code, but this gives light to a better way of handling large number of validation functions.

Comment: `Any` _will_ short-circuit. The question says this is not okay, but I wonder if it really is. In any case, your answer is mislabeled.

Comment: @Tim S.: You are right, `Any` *will* short circuit, but the functions have already been evaluated for their values, non-lazily, and therefore *their* evaluation *will not* short circuit. And that was what needed to be avoided. Once the functions have been evaluated for their values and their side effects are observed, it *is* okay to short circuit the evaluation of determining whether or not *any* of them returned `false`.

Comment: @user1387542: I'm not sure what you mean that this wouldn't make sense in your current code. It doesn't matter if the functions are elements of an array of functions or not, it is *their* values that we are putting in an array. It would certainly be easier if all the functions were in an array, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that your variable flags invalidity while the function checks for validity.
You can change the return value of each `IsValid` call to make it answer the question `IsInvalid`.
Simply add a `!` before each `IsValid` call.
The code would look like this:

```
bool hasAnyInvalid = false;
hasAnyInvalid |= !IsValidType1(...);
hasAnyInvalid |= !IsValidType2(...);
hasAnyInvalid |= !IsValidType3(...);
hasAnyInvalid |= !IsValidType4(...);

return hasAnyInvalid;
```